# How to show/hide buttons using jQuery and data()?

Tags: jquery, events, show-hide, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to show and hide certain buttons based on event click. I am using jQuery and the .data() method to handle this.

Here is my markup (note - I have many repeating divs in the doc with differing ids and I trying to hone in on particular ids for my event click):

```
<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="activate002007" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate002007" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit002007" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
  $( '.jq_activate' ).click(function() {
    $(this).data('reference','B1').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).data('reference','B2').css('display', 'inline');
    $(this).data('reference','B3').css('display', 'inline');
  });
```

I can't get the buttons to show and hide properly on click event. Any suggestions?

**Amendment**

I added another  group to show that the page has dozens of buttons and I am trying to hone in on only 1 set of buttons.

Comment: You're setting the data and CSS of `$(this)` all 3 times. I don't think that's what you want, but I can't figure out what you really want.

Comment: What do you think `.data('reference', 'B2')` means? It's not a filter that matches `data-reference="B2"`, it means to change `data-reference` to `B2`(actually it works on an internal jQuery cache, it doesn't update the attribute).

Comment: Could you explain clearly what you're trying to do? Which buttons should be displayed and hidden?

Comment: I amended my OQ to show there are many button groups on the page.

Comment: That doesn't help. Which ones are supposed to be hidden and shown? And why don't you use `.hide()` and `.show()`?

Comment: And what does `.data()` have to do with hiding and showing? Why are you changing the data of the buttons?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Refer to my OQ markup. When I click the activate button for `id="activate002007"` I want that activate button to `.hide()` and its partner deactivate and edit buttons to `.show()`. But I only want it to happen for this group, No other button group on the page. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried `.hide()` and `.show()`. Neither .css() or .show/hide() was getting the job done. So I think the problem is in the .data() target part.

Comment: What is `.data('reference', 'B1')` for?

Comment: I am not "trying" to change the data for the buttons. I am trying to find a way to target the buttons and show/hide them

Comment: `.data('reference', 'B1')` is my way of targeting the buttons to show/hide

Comment: What gave you the impression that `.data()` is used for targeting? It's used for retrieving or changing the data. If you want to target, use a selector like `$("button[data-reference=B1]")`

Comment: Got the answer :) Whoever wants this closed feel free to do so. Best.

Comment: Accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B2` and `B3` are `.siblings()` of `B1` so you should use `$(this).siblings()`

```js
$('.jq_activate').click(function() {
  $(this).data('reference', 'B1').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).siblings().data('reference', 'B2').css('display', 'inline');
  $(this).siblings().data('reference', 'B3').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
```

Recommended version, using `hide()` and `show()` instead of `css` property:

```js
$('.jq_activate').click(function() {
  $(this).data('reference', 'B1').hide();
  $(this).siblings('[data-reference="B2"]').show();
  $(this).siblings('[data-reference="B3"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The second `.siblings()` line is overriding what the first one did. Why do you have it?

Comment: @Barmar The first line make `B1` hide, right? second line just show `B2` and third line just show `B3` what's the problem?

Comment: Awesome @Pedram -- that solved it!! Thanks so much. Plus it is nice and clean and condensed and simple code...

Comment: and I'll revert back to show/hide()...I was trying everything I could think of and ended up with .css()

Comment: @H.Ferrence This answer is changing the data, which I don't think you want.

Comment: @H.Ferrence you are welcome. But check recommended version again. you can use data attributes selector instead of `data()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$('button')` instead of `$(this)` for the last two buttons. Also, create your query to search for all the `button` elements in that `div` where you actually click for the `B1` button. This will not affect all the buttons of other `div`

```js
$( '.jq_activate' ).click(function() {
   $(this).closest('div').find('button').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('reference') === 'B2' || $(this).data('reference') === 'B3'){
      $(this).css('display','inline');
    }
  });
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="activate001005" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001006" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>


<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: B1 should hide after click

Comment: The second and third lines operate on the same buttons.

Comment: But what about all the other `<button id="{many more}" data-reference="B2">` ? Won't they be effected as well @AnkitAgarwal?

Comment: That did not cut it...all of the other buttons on the page got impacted by the $('button') directive

Comment: You still have `$('button').data('reference','B3').css('display', 'inline');` that shows all the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(this)` for the button you clicked on, and `$(this).siblings()` for all the other buttons in the same group.

If you want to select buttons with a specific `data-reference`, use an attribute selector, not `.data()`. To stay within the same group, use `$(this).parent().find()`.

```js
$('.jq_activate').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('button[data-reference=B1]').hide();
  $(this).parent().find('button[data-reference=B2],button[data-reference=B3]').show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="activate001003" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate001003" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit001003" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="activate002007" class="jq_activate" data-reference="B1" style="display: inline;" type="button">B1</button>
  <button id="deactivate002007" class="jq_deactivate" data-reference="B2" style="display: none;" type="button">B2</button>
  <button id="edit002007" class="jq_edit" data-reference="B3" style="display: none;" type="button">B3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But OP want to call other button with data attribute

Comment: @Pedram I don't think so, I think he was just confused about what that does.

Comment: I think in this case OP should use `[data-reference='B2']` etc.. instead of `data()`